# I cannot control a turtle spawned in another machine

Tags: turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you. I can connect to roscore from machine #2. But, another problem.

I would like to control turtle (turtlesim example) in #1 using #2 keyboard.

So in #1,

$ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node

And in #2,

$ rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key

However, I couldn't control. And I also ran the 'rxgraph' util, it seems not connected.

What's the problem?

**Here's my roswtf result.**
**I confirmed that, I can connect to machine #1 via 11311 port by using netcat utility**

```
hyon-no2@hyon-no2-desktop:~$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
connection to [/rosout] timed out
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 2 error(s).

ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /rosout

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/rosout/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/rosout/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://hyon-no1-desktop:35930]
 * service [/rosout/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/rosout/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://hyon-no1-desktop:35930]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9633/i-cannot-control-a-turtle-spawned-in-another-machine./) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2011-04-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-04-04**:
For the record, this is a follow-up question to this one: http://answers.ros.org/question/593/rosnode-list-does-not-show-the-roscore-in-other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you refer to a host by hostname (in your example, you seem to be using `hyon-no1-desktop`), you must have some way to resolve that hostname to an IP address (e.g., using DNS, Avahi or `/etc/hosts`).

When your refer to a host by IP address (like `10.0.1.25`), you shouldn't have to enter that IP into `/etc/hosts`.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1